# PostgreSQL: how to get max() of GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called **history** with the fields **id**, **lastname**, **event** and **date**.

It saves events of persons that works in my office like "Entering office", "Exiting office", "Illness", "Holidays", etc.

I need to get the last event of every person.

This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT lastname, event, max(date)
FROM personshistory
GROUP BY lastname, event;
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? How does the output differ from what you need?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (lastname) ph.*
from personshistory
order by lastname, date desc;
```

`distinct on` is a very convenient Postgres extension.  It keeps one row for each value of the expressions in parentheses.  The specific row is determined by the `order by` clause -- based on the keys that follow the `distinct on` keys.

Answer (score 0):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT p.lastname, p.event, p.date
FROM personshistory p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM personshistory
  WHERE lastname = p.lastname and date > p.date 
)
```

or join your query (without the `event` column) to the table:

```
SELECT p.lastname, p.event, p.date
FROM personshistory p INNER JOIN (
  SELECT lastname, MAX(date) maxdate
  FROM personshistory
  GROUP BY lastname
) g on g.lastname = p.lastname and g.maxdate = p.date
```